# NoClassDefFoundError in JBOSS EAP6.4

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

When I deploy my war in JBOSS EAP6.4 I get below error inspite of having jackson-mapper-asl.1.9.2.jar in my classpath and setting to read in deployment structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deploy" />
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Below is the log stack

```
     Thread-11733 2016-09-12 06:12:10,169 | WARN  | session=       | user=           | org.hornetq.jms.client | HQ122001: Unhandled exception thrown from onMessage: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONWithPadding (Module "deploy:main" from local module loader @ed17bee (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: /vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules,/vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/BZ1281963,/vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base,/vend/hybris/OTMM16/Media-Manager/mediamanagement,/vend/hybris/OTMM16/Media-Manager/mediamanagement)))
    at com.artesia.event.services.EventListenerManager$EventListenerWrapper.onMessage(EventListenerManager.java:101)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.JMSMessageListenerWrapper.onMessage(JMSMessageListenerWrapper.java:98)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1117)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:57)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1252)
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:105)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONWithPadding (Module "deploy:main" from local module loader @ed17bee (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: /vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules,/vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/BZ1281963,/vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base,/vend/hybris/OTMM16/Media-Manager/mediamanagement,/vend/hybris/OTMM16/Media-Manager/mediamanagement)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:124)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:171)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.pipeline.jersey.Exports$3.create(Exports.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.pipeline.jersey.Exports$3.create(Exports.java:65)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.DefaultBuilder.build(DefaultBuilder.java:200)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.DefaultBuilder$1.create(DefaultBuilder.java:138)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.DefaultBuilder.build(DefaultBuilder.java:200)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.DefaultBuilder$1.create(DefaultBuilder.java:138)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.DefaultBuilder.build(DefaultBuilder.java:200)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration.create(Configuration.java:119)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.MediaService.create(MediaService.java:47)
    at com.example.AzureAPIProxy.getMediaService(AzureAPIProxy.java:250)
    at com.artesia.event.services.EventListenerManager$EventListenerWrapper.onMessage(EventListenerManager.java:85)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonSerializableWithType
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializableWithType from [Module "deploy:main" from local module loader @ed17bee (finder: local module finder @2a33fae0 (roots: /vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules,/vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/BZ1281963,/vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base,/vend/hybris/OTMM16/Media-Manager/mediamanagement,/vend/hybris/OTMM16/Media-Manager/mediamanagement))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    ... 55 more
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have fixed this issue by adding jar to my deploy module. Looking if there is another approach to fix the issue, as of now adding jar to deploy module has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the "deploy" folder is probably not located at the correct folder tree level under modules. I would also recommend not naming it a "deploy" folder to avoid confusions with the actual deploy.

Your folder structure should look like this if you want to get it working as you have it referenced.

`vend/hybris/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/deploy/main` . Under this folder you should have a `module.xml` file and a reference to the necessary jars along with the jars themselves.

Comment: we have deploy folder created at other location and we are referencing it in our project. before adding code related to Jackson jar, it is loading jars at runtime and it is working as expected. Only after adding code related to Jackson it is throwing us errors.

Comment: The deploy folder is being used by 3rd Party application which we use and we are receiving the required jars from that application

Comment: So you have an external modules (outside of JBoss) folder too?

Comment: yeah, our 3rd party application is installed outside of JBOSS root folder and via configuration in 3rd party application it is loaded when jboss starts.

Comment: Then you will need to modify your standalone.sh or domain.sh by adding "${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}:${your_third_party_deploy_folder}" reference on every occurrence on the script. Alternatively you can follow what I suggested above.