# HTTP Post with ionic 3

Tags: java, angular, web-services, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to call a local rest webservice to test a simple login function
I have tried with a Get function and it works fine now I'm trying with Post function and I have no idea how to pass parameters to my request

```js
import { HttpClient,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Storage} from "@ionic/storage";
// import { HttpParams } from '@angular/http';

/*
  Generated class for the RestProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
  */
  @Injectable()
  export class RestProvider {

    apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyTutorials/api/crunchifyService';
    user : any;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) {
      console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
    //console.log(this.storage.get('user'));
  }

//   getUsers() {
//   return new Promise(resolve => {
//     this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
//       resolve(data);
//       this.storage.set('user', data);
//     }, err => {
//       console.log(err);
//     });
//   });
// }
  //--------------------------------------------
  getUsers() {
  //   let data = new URLSearchParams();
  // data.append('user', 'khaled');
  // data.append('pass', 'khaled');
  //data =Object.assign(urlSearchParams, {search: "person"});

  const data = new HttpParams()
  .set('user', 'khaled').set('pass', 'khaled');

  this.http
  .post(this.apiUrl, data, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
  .subscribe(data => {
    alert('ok');
  }, error => {
    console.log(error.json());
  });
}
}
```

And the Java part

```js
@POST
 @Path("/crunchifyService")
 @Produces("application/json")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 public Modele add (String user, String pass) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
   
  Auth_Ctrl auth = new Auth_Ctrl();
  int result =auth.connect(user, pass);
  
  return auth.info(result);
 }
```

the problem is that when I debug the server part all my parameters are null and there is no error in the client part

Comment: is `data` a JSON object?

Comment: no, it's not a JSON object how can i convert it to a JSON object

Comment: I agree with the answer provided by Chris, but if you are indeed using query params, you need to use `HttpParams` in your angular code. `URLSearchParams` belongs to the deprecated `HttpModule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whom it might interest i modified my code like that
i added a class "Log" which contains two fields user and pass in my webservice following this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001719/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-codehaus-jackson-map-jsonserializablewitht) 
and then i modified my method like that

```js
@POST
 @Path("/crunchifyService")
 @Produces("application/json")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 public Modele auth (Log user) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
   
  Auth_Ctrl auth = new Auth_Ctrl();
  int result =auth.connect(user.user, user.pass);
  
  return auth.info(result);
 }
```

and i noticed that i need to add `jackson-mapper-asl` to my classpath
and after that everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@QueryParam` which uses get parameters. These parameters should be included in the url. The `http.post` method encodes the data as `application/json` inside the body of the request.

You should change either one of these to match the other.
My advise would be to change the java here to consume `applications/json` due to the security concerns of putting a password in the url

Comment: thanks for your help, so i have edited my post with my new code i'm using now `HttpParams` and added `@Consumes("application/json")` before my methode but the problem now is that i get `user=khaled&pass=khaled` as my first param and nothing as my seconde param